# How can I resize PrimeFaces for all?

Tags: primefaces

I found questions and answers for this question. But none of them works.

I have a maven project.

I wrote `resources/css/default.css`.

My final jar looks like this.

```
    97 Mon Nov 07 20:09:24 KST 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:24 KST 2016 META-INF/
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:22 KST 2016 resources/
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:22 KST 2016 resources/css/
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:22 KST 2016 WEB-INF/
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:22 KST 2016 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Mon Nov 07 20:09:22 KST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/
  1113 Mon Nov 07 19:48:22 KST 2016 index.xhtml
   344 Mon Nov 07 20:09:16 KST 2016 resources/css/default.css
   339 Mon Nov 07 19:14:30 KST 2016 WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
4007587 Mon Nov 07 19:03:30 KST 2016 WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-6.0.jar
   976 Mon Nov 07 19:14:30 KST 2016 WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Here comes my `default.css`.

```
$ unzip -p target/....war resources/css/default.css

/*.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {*/
.ui-widget {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you include your custom style in you pages? If so, how? Please provide code.

Comment: @irieill That was my problem. You should put a new answer. Don't be shy.

Comment: please learn some basics about html/css, web development in general and only then jsf....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSF page (.xhtml), include:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css" />
</h:head>
```

Comment: Are you @irieill?